# average of a field inside of a text in kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, text, kibana, timelion

I have some logs in kibana with this message:

```
message: '{ "Type": "successfully created", "Count": 6, "ElapsedTime": 2004, "Id": "189f6293-21a1-4a74-a332-34369a0ebd0d"}'
```

How i can create a chart with timelion that shows average value of `ElapsedTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to extract the fields/json-keys from the message field.

The message field itself is of type text, meaning you can do full-text searches on it. In order to use the values of `ElapsedTime` to build visualizations, it has to be an own field inside the document either with type integer or keyword.

If you use Logstash, you can set up a pipeline using the [json filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html). It will extract the JSON object inside the message field and store the key-value-pairs as separate fields in your event/document.

Comment: I am using `nlog` and i have to send json string. Also I hope that i can use elasticsearch timelion only to parse json string.

Comment: The json string is fine. But in order to make all fields inside that json string searchable themselves (not just the message field) you need to index them as own fields inside your document.